# One page site design + blog implementation

Tags: design, interaction

I'm designing a one page agency site. Everything works great in this format, except for the blog/news section(s.) The problematic issue is not necessarily displaying the blog content inline, but how to show archives and allow navigation in the blog from the single page. I don't think we'll allow searching from within the site, so no results pages. I think we'll rely on organic search to drive traffic to specific pages.

**Has anyone designed a site that implements a blog into a one-page design?**

What are the key insights that make this design approach work? What are the usability problems which had the greatest impact, and what issues turned out to less a problem?

Supporting examples welcome!

Comment: Are you asking for a list of sites that use a one-page blog design, or are you asking how you can effectively set up a blog's flow on a single page? The list question is off topic but I think the latter Q could be a good fit. You can still ask answerers for examples to prove their points.

Comment: The latter. But it's not purely a blog-style site. There will be a blog component. So, really, I would like examples of how some have integrated a blog into a one-page site. I see issues of running content inline, depending on length and content. A lightbox stretching screen height _might_ work. Then the question arises, "How shall we handle archives,etc.?" Just seeing if there are any innovative, intuitive solutions others have used. I can see it getting complex quickly.
Edit: Hit enter. Whoops.

Comment: By one page what exactly do you mean? Like Twitter's "one page" where everything is loaded in via AJAX but visual pages are distinct, or just that everything is in a single, continuous vertical page?

Comment: Apologies. Didn't understand the ask.

https://www.simple.com/ is a good example of the one-page design we're going for. No infinity-load. Simple does have a blog, but send it out to individual pages. We'll do something similar if a reasonable solution doesn't come up. I just wanted to see what's out there. 

Edit: Pressed Enter again.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. Simple is a good example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There don't appear to be any that don't either link out to other pages for articles or load older articles incrementally.

You can find a whole bunch of terrific examples of single-page websites on [One Page Love](http://onepagelove.com/), and on that site you can search for "blog" and "news" to list some examples.

The closest I can find, then, is something like the [System of a Down](http://www.systemofadown.com/) site is a single-pager which AJAX-loads in older articles when you choose "Previous Posts". Some other ideas include [Idea Exhibit](http://ideaexhibit.com/) (which loads older articles once you navigate to them), or something more like [Happy Cog](http://happycog.com/) (which links off the page for other articles).

Comment: Thank you very much for the link to One Page Love. Hadn't seen that before!

Answer (score 1):

This is vanilla: http://googleblog.blogspot.in/

This is cassatta: http://googleblog.blogspot.in/view

Don't forget the browse the awe-inspiring arrangements on the second link.

Comment: These aren't one-page sites. They are pure blogs.

Comment: Welcome to UX.SE A'n'User! Could you provide some more detail in your answer, such as a description of the sites or some screenshots?

Comment: OP here. I think A'n'User was showing how these views could be scaled down as a page component. If so, there's some pretty interesting solutions there.